# error ldap can't contact ldap server in php

Tags: php, ldap

I have tried a new code but still same the following mistakes **Invalid Credential**

```
<?php
$username = "cwahyono";
$password = "1234";
$ldapconfig['host'] = '10.0.0.120';
$ldapconfig['port'] = '389';
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=10,dc=0,dc=0,dc=120';
$ldapconfig['usersdn'] = 'cn=admin';
$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10);
$dn="uid=".$username.",".$ldapconfig['usersdn'].",".$ldapconfig['basedn'];
if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $password)) {
    echo "LOGIN BERHASIL!";
} else {
 echo "Login Failed: Please check your username or password";
}
?>
```

i'm a newbie ldap please help me out from this problem

Comment: `ldap_connect('ldap://127.0.0.1');` would mean you have an LDAP server on your system.  So do you?  This probably needs to be changed to the IP of your LDAP system.  `$ldap_dn = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";`.  Does this user exist?  Check with your LDAP admin.  And you probably have to provide a password for this user.

Comment: @Nic3500 i have to try your advice then i have to fill the password and still following mistakes **Invalid Credentials**

Comment: If you have admin access to this LDAP, change the password of user `cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com` to something and use that.

Comment: @Nic3500 i have tried a new code but still same following mistakes

Comment: @Nic3500 and i have to update my code on my question